# Insert external page html into a page html

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to load/insert an external html page into my web page. Example :

```
<b>Hello this is my webpage</b>
You can see here an interresting information :

XXXX

Hope you enjoyed
```

the **XXXX** should be replaced by a small script (the smaller as possible) that load a page like http://www.mySite.com/myPageToInsert.html

I found the following code with jquery :

```
<script>$("#testLoad").load("http://www.mySite.com/myPageToInsert.html");</script>    
<div id="testLoad"></div>
```

I would like the same without using an external javascript library as jquery...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 solutions for this (2 that I know at least):

1. Iframe -> this one is not so recommended
2. Send an ajax request to the desired page.

Here is a small script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function createRequestObject() {
    var obj;
    var browser = navigator.appName;
    if (browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return obj;
}

function sendReq(req) {   
    var http = createRequestObject();
    http.open('get', req);
    http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
    http.send(null);
}

function handleResponse() {    
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        var response = http.responseText;
        document.getElementById('setADivWithAnIDWhereYouWantIt').innerHTML=response;
    }
}

 sendReq('yourpage');
//previously </script> was not visible
</script>
```

Comment: getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: http is not defined

Comment: had to add this list to make it work: http = createRequestObject()

Comment: is this up to date?

Comment: Should still work fine if you need only that and you don't want to include any libs. Although js libs evolved a lot since then so I would suggest using jQuery ajax instead since it provides more flexibility (5 years ago you could have many reasons not to use a lib... now... eh... not so much; internet evolved to the point where the 100k of the lib is not a tragedy to load and most conflicts between different libs are known and pointed out or fixed).

Answer (score 4):

Would an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) fit the bill?

```
<b>Hello this is my webpage</b>
You can see here an interresting information :

<iframe id="extFrame" src="http://www.mySite.com/myPageToInsert.html"></iframe>

Hope you enjoyed
```

You can set the `src` attribute of your iframe element using plain old javascript to switch out the page for another

Comment: Thx, I didn't think about iframe because it's sometimes problematic on some web site... But I should reconsider it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are in the Jquery source code.

you can see more details here [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)