# Load html content of a file to another web page

Tags: php, html, ajax

So I have www.siteA.com and www.siteB.com. Site A is my main site and site B is where I store some few web pages mostly html pages. I want to load a webpage from site B into a page of site A. So far, I have search SO about how to do this and found this one [Insert external page html into a page html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967629/insert-external-page-html-into-a-page-html/4967705#4967705) but it wont work on me. Here is the code I used from the link above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function createRequestObject() 
{
   var obj;
   var browser = navigator.appName;
   if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
      obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }else{
      obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   return obj;
}

function sendReq(req) 
{    
   http.open('get', req);
   http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
   http.send(null);
}

function handleResponse() 
{    
   if (http.readyState == 4)
   {
      var response = http.responseText;
      document.getElementById('here').innerHTML=response;
   }
}

 sendReq('http://www.siteB.com/file.html');
 </script>
 </head>

 <body >
     <div id="here"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**www.siteB.com/file.html** file only contains this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

 <body >
     <h1>hello world!</h1>
     <p><img src="http://www.siteB.com/img.jpg"/></p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Any idea why it wont work on me? Or is it possible to load an external page from another domain?

Comment: First have you considered using jQuery for the AJAX stuff - means you won't have to worry about the differences in browsers and could save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: You need to use jquery provided ajax call with the protocol jsonp.

Comment: Use an `<iframe>` - you cant do what you are trying to do, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: @Benjamin - What's wrong with thanking? Is it bad to be polite and all on this website?

Comment: @AnnaGee Nothing wrong really, but please read [this question on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/175147) to understand the philosophy of Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is subject to the [**Same-origin Policy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). It can't access content from a domain that's different from its current domain.

Since you've tagged this question as PHP, I assume you're using it, and you can retrieve content from that page as follows:

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.siteB.com/file.html');
echo $contents;
?>
```

Then, you can redirect your XMLHttpRequest to that PHP file, which will retrieve the content for you.

Answer (score 0):

JS cannot communicate between sites like that. Since you tagged PHP, you can use PHP.

```
document.getElementById('here').innerHTML=JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode(file_get_contents('http://www.siteB.com/file.html')); ?>);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to show another page from a website, why not use iframes?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: I tried this one also and it works but some people said using iframe is not really a good idea. So I was kinda hesitant to use it. But I guess I will just have to settle on this one if everything fails. thank you.

Comment: @AnnaGee Read this Q&A, to understand if you should use iFrames: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice

Comment: -1 Frames hurt SEO, feel dated to the user and are problematic, not to mention frames are subject to the same-origin policy too.