# Getting HTML from another file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have several html pages and they all use a div that is exactly the same.

I want to have this same div in a separate file so that every time I have to make changes I won't have to copy the new version over and over again.

I don't know where to start and the proper terminology for this, but I'm confined to html and javascript.

Comment: You can use iframe..http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967629/insert-external-page-html-into-a-page-html

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the new frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for Underscore Templates and how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery you can use ajax.load as so:

```
$( "#yourDivId" ).load( "yourfile.html" );
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/