# Javascript change div content

Tags: javascript, html

My site has a one `<div>` for the header, one for navigation-panel and one for the content.

For the navigation-links i use

```
<p class="blue"><label onclick="goFor('test')"> -> TEST! <- </label> </p>
```

and my JS:

```
function goFor(destination) 
{ 
    document.getElementById("content").load(destination+'.php'); 
}
```

in this case, the content-div should change to the file "test.php".

but Firebug says: `document.getElementById(...).load is not a function`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: load is a jQuery function. I've not seen a native load function before (I could be wrong)

Comment: `load` function is a jQuery one, check out [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: oh...is there a not jQuery function to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $("#content").load(something) instead of document.getElementById.

Or... make an ajax request and load answer in that div.

For an ajax request with no lib, you can check my script here (first answer): [Insert external page html into a page html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967629/insert-external-page-html-into-a-page-html/4967705#4967705). Note the success handle as you want it... with document.getElementById.

Comment: .load kind of suggests jQuery

Comment: I don't think op wants jquery... my guess is he actually wants the ajax request.

Comment: i dont want to use Ajax or Jquery. Isnt there a normal way? So i have to reload the whole page?

Comment: If your file is .php, and you want it parsed... you have 2 choices: ajax or reload. If your file is something else... depends. Also... why you don't want ajax? You do know that a reload makes the same request you would do by ajax.

Comment: So i think i should do the reload, whick takes the speed-brake and load to the user-site, not the server.

Comment: Anything you do to get a .php will load the server. .php is parsed on server. Also at reload you make a request... is how http works.

Comment: really?..why is the time to re-load about 3 secs, and the Ajax about 8.5 sec's (measured by Firefox)

Comment: Cache. You can also cache the ajax. Clear cache, press f5, you'll get 8.5 sec. Cache the ajax, you'll get the 3 sec.