# Embedding too small on mobile (bandcamp)

Tags: html, css

As the title says, i'm trying to embed a Bandcamp profile to my page. However, on mobile the text just looks far too small.

There's no option to change it (as far as i can see) in the code of using the embed function from the Bandcamp website.

```
<iframe class="bandcamp" style="border: 0; width: 700px; height: 340px;" src="https://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=2225879202/size=large/bgcol=333333/linkcol=0f91ff/artwork=small/transparent=true/" seamless><a href="http://northernnightlights1.bandcamp.com/album/northern-nightlights-sampler">Singles by Northern Nightlights</a></iframe>
```

[Here's a picture to help illustrate the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxMrE.png)

I am still really new to coding, so I've never worked with iframe before.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Try with ajax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967629/insert-external-page-html-into-a-page-html

Comment: Will give it a go!
Haven't dabbled in JS much. So i can't confirm if this will work yet. Might take me a while!

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add a viewport meta. There are numerous parameters you can declare, but the one I think you need is the width=device-width parameter. Works for me. Give it a shot.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove the explicit `size=large` option from the URL, resulting in this:

```
<iframe class="bandcamp" style="border: 0; width: 700px; height: 340px;" src="https://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=2225879202/bgcol=333333/linkcol=0f91ff/artwork=small/transparent=true/" seamless><a href="http://northernnightlights1.bandcamp.com/album/northern-nightlights-sampler">Singles by Northern Nightlights</a></iframe>
```

Comment: This sadly just makes the player itself smaller. Doesn't affect the text. I appreciate the help though!